# Hide query string from URL asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have this following url:

http://www.example.com?user=Ana
and I want to get  http://www.example.com?Ana

How can I get it?

Comment: Look up URL rewriting and routing (as wudzik commented).

Comment: It is trivial to get a value from query string (assuming you've already know/found how to do that)... But are you really sure you are looking for such unusual format? (i.e. it is more common to specify arguments in the path ".../foo/bar/Ana" or use regular query parameters as you "don't want" option)

Answer (score 5):

You can route `example.com/Ana` to Home/Index with parameter (you can change controller and action to what is needed). Just add new route to your routing dictionary

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UserPage",                                              
    "{controller}/{action}/{user}",                           
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", user = "" }  
);
```

You can read more about routing [here at ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

NOTE:
as Alexei Levenkov said it requires .Net MVC to route it that way.

Comment: While this is good suggestion it is not going to give result OP requested - "...?Ana". Also note that it requires ASP.Net MVC which was not mentioned in the post...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeah, I made an assumption and I'm waiting for a comment from OP. I know it won't produce `?Ana` so I said in first sentence it will rout to "/Ana". Thanks for pointing it :)

Comment: @wudzik , sorry for edited question, yeah I want it produce `?Ana`